# get value by putting 2 other parameters of the same set from json array in fastAPI

Tags: python, json, fastapi

I want to get the value of pred by putting node1 and node2 value:

THIS MY DATA ARRAY

```
prediction_data =[
  { "node1": 0, "node2": 1, "pred": 0},
  { "node1": 0, "node2": 476, "pred":0.352956 },
  { "node1": 0, "node2": 494, "pred":0.769988 },
  { "node1": 1, "node2": 505, "pred":0.463901 },
  { "node1": 9, "node2": 68 , "pred":1.238807},
    ]
```

THIS WHAT I HAVE TRIED, I'm new in APIs

1. this gives me all data

```
@app.get("/data/")
async def get_all_predictions(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 10):
    return prediction_data[skip : skip + limit]
```

2. this is the wanted function but of course the wrong one

```
@app.get("/data/{node1,node2}")
async def getPredOfN1andN2(node1,node2):
  if (node1 in prediction_data.node1) and (node2 in prediction_data.node2):
    result = prediction_data[pred]
  return result
```

for example, I want to write 0 and 1and get as result pred = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter a list by using the built-in `filter` function:

```
async def getPredOfN1andN2(node1: int, node2: int):
    matching = list(filter(lambda x: x['node1'] == node1 and x['node2'] == node2, prediction_data))

    return matching[0]['pred'] if matching else None
```

If it's possible to have multiple matches, drop the `[0]` and just return the whole list instead.

Comment: thank you so much for answering me, but it gave me null instead of 0 when I put Node1 = 0 and node2 =1   `  @app.get("/prediction")
async def getPredOfN1andN2(node1, node2):
    matching = list(filter(lambda x: x['node1'] == node1 and x['node2'] == node2, prediction_data))

    return matching['pred'] if matching else None
 `

Comment: You're going to have to make sure the types are the same, so `async def getPredOfN1andN2(node1: int, node2: int):`